# Build Object path with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

```
var area = "residenceArea1";
var type = "residenceType1";
var year = "constructionYear1";
var obj = {
    "residenceType1": [
        {
            "constructionYear1": [
                {
                    "residenceArea1": 103,
                    "residenceArea2": 82
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "constructionYear2": [
                {
                    "residenceArea1": 62
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "residenceType2": [
        {
            "constructionYear1": [
                {
                    "residenceArea1": 83
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

console.log(object.residenceType1[0].constructionYear1[0].residenceArea1) //103
```

This object is longer but I have shortened it for this question. Is there a way to make the objects path be set by my 3 variables? something like this:

```
console.log(object.type[0].year[0].area)
```

The variables change depending what radio buttons the user chooses and that's why I want to set the path with variables. Also could this object be made easier so we don't need to specify `[0]` for the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you're asking for is something like this:

```
obj[type][0][year][0][area]
```

The square-bracket notation allows an arbitrary expression to be used in the key lookup of the object.
Note that the key will always be converted to a string during lookup.

The following are equivalent:

```
var type = 'residenceType1';

obj.residenceType1            // dot-notation
obj['residenceType1']         // square-bracket notation with string expression
obj[type]                     // square-bracket notation with variable expression
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is accessing via the `[]` with named property passed in:

```
console.log(object[type][0][year][0][area]);
```